# How do I get a list of all distributions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distribution

Is there a way to get all parametric distributions in Mathematica as a list without typing it all?

```
{NormalDistribution[x,y], UniformDistribution[{x,y}], ExponentialDistribution[x]...}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Names["*Distribution"]
```

and use this list of symbol to construct what you need. You might want to refer to the help for "ToExpression", "StringJoin".